# Using template resulting type for auto

Tags: c++, stl, c++-templates

In case I don’t want to call the `std::ranges::subrange` in the code below and want only to create a `range` object which will hold the results of the template function call later, what is the correct way to declare `range`?

I guess [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) should help here, but I can’t figure out the way to represent the type.

**Reasoning**

I will be able to provide first data for `range` only in the loop which will follow and I will need to use it after the loop ends, so I need this object outside the loop and not initialized at the beginning. Sometimes this is hard or even next to impossible.

**The code**

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values(10);

    // How to replace this with default initialization for range based on type only, 
    // without the call to std::ranges::subrange ?
    auto range = std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end());

    while (...) {
        range = std::ranges::equal_range(...);
    }

    size_t last_range_size = range.size();
}
```

Comment: there is no loop in the code you posted. Perhaps an immediately invoked lambda expression will do, but I am not sure if I understand the use case

Comment: what do you mean with " but I can’t figure out the way to represent the type." ? `decltype(std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end()))` is the type

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai OP don't want to explicitly write `std::ranges::subrange` as you've done inside the decltype. See the comment in their code that says: *"without the call to std::ranges::subrange"*

Comment: but do they want to write? It seems like all relevant parts have been left out and the code only shows what they dont want

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I updated the code. The first version was shortened for brevity; I was sure this was obvious from the text. Sorry for bad wording then. Does it work now?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I was sure that the type is what I could put to decltype and it, really is. Damn I just mixed the syntax and tried `auto decltype(...)` instead of just `decltype(...)`. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @user12002570, my bad, sorry. "463.." is correct here, I just messed up the syntax. The code with decltype(std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end())) won't call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type you need is : `std::ranges::subrange<std::vector<int>::iterator>` as shown here

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values(10);

    // How to replace this with default initialization for range based on type only, 
    // without the call to std::ranges::subrange ?
    auto range = std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end());

    // From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange
    // it follows this is the type : 
    using range_t = std::ranges::subrange<std::vector<int>::iterator>;

    // And this verifies the type equality
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(range),range_t>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was looking just for the `decltype(std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(), values.end()))` as the user "463..." helped me to understand, but you approach could help in variations, as well. Feel free to update your question with the variant, if you like.